# Python evaluating a local fabric curl command

Tags: python, curl, fabric

Seems like this should work but it doesn't really. I've played around with various methods like using range, seeing if the expression evaluates to True, etc. I use `local` to run the command locally with fabric.

This is what it looks like now:

```
def test_health_check():
    test = local('curl -I -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n" --user username:username --location-mylocation "http://my.test.server:8180/something/something/something" -o /dev/null | cut -d " " -f 1')
    if test == 200:
        print "success"
    else:
        print "failure"
```

If I set the if test portion to `if test >= 200:` then it evaluates True but evaluates false for anything else. I want to be able to return True if the range is 200 thru 302. Also, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by my bro:

Assuming your curl command is set up to return the status code, I think you’d want the second arg of your
`local`
call to be True, so
`local(‘curl stuff’, True)`
as the docs say local is not capable of printing *and* capturing output simultaneously. The default value for the second arg is False, which is capture. You want capture.